# Why is setup.py installing old files?

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py

I'm working on a python module for a larger system. I did a setup.py package for installing it in the main module. It worked correctly, but then i did some changes to my module, mainly modified the names of the py files, and reorganize a bunch of classes.

Then I updated the version of the module, uninstall the old one with pip, and install the new version using python setup.py install and when i try to import in ipython found that i got the older, erased module.

Found it quite odd and checked my virtualenv lib folder and found both versions of the module, with the old classes structure and the new one. And both usable, as I imported both in ipython and tested it.

It doesn't raises any problem, as I can simply use the newest version, but is confusing. Any idea why this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't install with `pip`, you can't uninstall with `pip`, so you never actually uninstalled the old version. `python setup.py install` will install different versions, but typically they install on top of the old versions (except for the `.egg-info` file or directory). You don't say how exactly the two versions were living side-by-side, because `setup.py` (or `pip`) won't rename `site-packages/my_module` to `my_module_v1`, for example. I assume that you changed the directory structure and `.py` file names enough that the two versions could coexist in the same parent directory, so in IPython you could run `from my_module import OldClassName` and `from my_module import NewClassName`.

Comment: could also be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967441/djangos-manage-py-shows-old-commands

Comment: But how can we fix it? Removing the files from the environment did not help.

Comment: @Sören running `python setup.py install` should have created some folders like `build` in the same folder as `setup.py`.  If you run `python setup.py clean --all` it will delete the `build` folder.  Then, you should be able to run `python setyp.py install` and it will not have the old code.  I was put onto this scent by @Chris's comment above

Answer (score 4):

You can try installing using `pip` from the `setup.py` file using `pip install -e .` in the directory  . This installs the package in [editable mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/?highlight=editable#editable-installs). It installs any change you make to the code.

Comment: Thank you @gkhnavarro, that is more in line with what I want!  For anyone else, the correct usage would be `pip install -e <path/url>`.  Note, the path should lead to the directory housing `setup.py`.